# When I replace some patterns of a string, can I use a regular expression for the replacement to be replaced?

Tags: r, regex

I have a question about replacing string.

```
string_before <- "aaajohn bbbjohn cccjohn johnaaa johnbbb johnccc"
string_after <- "aaajane bbbjane cccjane johnaaa johnbbb johnccc"
```

I want to replace above `string_before` into `string_after`.
(pattern is `[^ ]+john`, replacement is `[^ ]+jane`.).
Is there any way to use regular expressions for pattern and replacement, too?

Comment: I would go with gsub(). did you try it out?

Comment: You just need to use a [**capturing group**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) with a [**backreference** in the replacement pattern](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html). Or, if you use `\Bjohn`, you may just replace with `jane` since `\B` is a zero-width assertion that does not put the matched chars into the match value. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
gsub("(\\S+)john", "\\1jane", x)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XwwGvQ/2)

Here, `(\\S+)` captures any 1+ chars other than whitespace into Group 1 and then `john` is just matched, and the whole match is replaced with the value in Group 1 (`\1`) and `jane` substring.

Or, if you just want to match `john` not at the beginning of a "word", you may also consider

```
gsub("\\Bjohn", "jane", x)
```

where `\B` is a non-word boundary position (the `john` must be preceded with a word char, a letter, digit or `_`).

[R demo](https://ideone.com/Pg9PiP):

```
string_before <- "aaajohn bbbjohn cccjohn johnaaa johnbbb johnccc"
string_after <- gsub("(\\S+)john", "\\1jane", string_before)
string_after
# => [1] "aaajane bbbjane cccjane johnaaa johnbbb johnccc"
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple `gsub` solution that works for OPs example data:

```
# Replace john and space after it with jane and space 
string_after <- gsub("john ", "jane ", string_before)
```

And this solution searches for `john` at the end of the word (safer):

```
gsub("john\\>", "jane", c(string_before, "qwerjohn"))
[1] "aaajane bbbjane cccjane johnaaa johnbbb johnccc"
[2] "qwerjane"
```

Comment: In the second solution, `gsub("\\wjohn", "\\wjane", c(string_before, "qwerjohn"))`, you replace the match (a word char and `john`) with `"wjane"`. It is wrong.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you! Fixed

Comment: Yeah, but 1) the first solution is wrong as it will replace `john` with `jane` in `johnaaa` (not expected, see OP), and 2) `[^ ]+john` pattern implies the `john` does not occur only at the end of the word, it implies that `john` cannot occur at the beginning of a word.